# Disabling print option in pdf when opening pdf file from sharepoint library using sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, pdf

i want to disable pdf options from pdf file while opening pdf file from sharepoint library in sharepoint 2007.

Comment: Can you elaborate. What PDF Options do you want to disable? The ability to print or copy from the file?

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with sharepoint but rather the pdf itself. Google has lots of information on blocking printing with various programs, as well as ways to get around this block.

here is an article on how to disable print in acrobat - http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Miscellaneous/Q_20640736.html

Comment: If he wants to do it from SharePoint then this is a very valid question, with a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using Information Rights Management with Share Point.

See this link: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointecm/thread/62a45b16-4f0c-467e-8bf6-7338ea0f4b7d

You will need to install a PDF protector on your web front end, and configure the sharepoint library etc.